# Distance of 7-ary dual code

Tags: coding-theory

How would I go about proving the statement: if $D \subseteq \mathbb{F}_7^n$ is a self-dual code, then $2<d(D)<(n+3)/2$.

Where $d(D)$ is the minimum distance of the code D.

I'm not sure where to go from the fact that since $D$ is self dual the code is also self orthogonal and $n=2k$.

Comment: what have you thought about, "I am not sure how.." does not show enough effort.

Comment: To show a minimum (but IMHO sufficient) amount of work you could explain why a self-dual code over $\Bbb{F}_7$ cannot have words of weight two.